# Best app for sharing sensitive documentation?

Tags: open-source, osx

I work for a small web development firm that needs to share some sensitive technical documents between our remote developers. We have about 10 developers all using Macs. Essentially we're looking for these features:

- Data needs to be encrypted when its stored not just when it is sent.
- Preferably cloud based.
- Ability to set permissions on documents so that only specific people can access it.
- Open source or inexpensive.

We've floated a few ideas around but I wanted to see if anyone had recommendations.

Comment: Just a suggestion, Mega Cloud gives 50GB of encrypted storage (plus you can encrypt your files on upload) and allows you to invite users per folder.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially I do not have **the** answer you are looking for, just some suggestions that might be interesting to you. I recently encountered the same problem and we settled for the p2p solution.

### A p2p based solution

*So your 2nd point would not be accomplished*

We first used [getsync](http://www.getsync.com/) which is a fee software from BitTorrent. It is however not open source which lead us to migrate to [syncthing](http://www.syncthing.net/) which is free and open source.

Personally I like syncthing a lot and started to use it to sync all kind of things, e.g. with my android phone.

The **3th point** can be accomplished with specific folders for each developer. This is the main disadvantage in my eyes as it might lead to some restructuring of the data you are planning to share.

### Free cloud-based solutions

Most of those I haven't looked at in details, so here are just the links:

- [encryshare](http://encryshare.com/) If you believe what they say then this might be an interesting solution.
- [wetransfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/)
- [minbox](https://minbox.com/) Claims to be the better/cheaper version of wetransfer.
- etc. (if you check for alternatives, you'll find plenty)

### A build your own cloud based solution

You could use cloud services and run your own cloud. [Here](http://matthewlai.ca/blog/?p=1545) you find a solution with using [seafile](http://seafile.com) and [Amazone's S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). Seafile which is an open source alternative to [owncloud](https://owncloud.com/).

You could also go all-homemade and use a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/) or a [Banana Pi](http://www.bananapi.org/) and run your own cloud. It seems that for this approach [seafile](http://seafile.com) is the preferred software as it runs smoother than eg. Owncloud. [Here](http://draptik.github.io/blog/2014/04/21/installing-seafile-on-raspberry-pi/) is one of many installation guides.

Hope this might be of some use to you.